# Is there a version of LocalStorage but for each URL instead of origin?

Tags: javascript, html, server, client, storage

I'm trying to store some data on my client-side. And I have looked into localStorage, but the problem is that the data is shared among pages if they are the same origin. What if I want, for example, to store data separately on hello.com/app1 and hello.com/app2 (which are from the same origin, but different URLs). In other words, is there a version of localStorage but for each URL? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. You can design a naming convention for your local storage items to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... However, I actually want the different URLs to not be able to access the data from others. And I suppose using a naming convention would not solve that issue?

Comment: JavaScript's underlying assumption is that everyone using the same domain is working together, and it doesn't block any communication between these pages.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is session storage and a server to validate each user/url I guess. I imagine your "apps" have to be authenticated somehow.

If you want to avoid the server and just go crazy with it, you can stringify the localstorage for each endpoint and let the users enter a password to encrypt the content. It can then be decrypted later when they enter it again.

But again, a server is the best way to go.